# rpart plot text shorter

Tags: r, rpart

I am using the `prp` function from the `rpart.plot` package to plot a tree. For categorical data like states, it gives a really long list of variables and makes it less readable. Is there any way to wrap text to two or more lines if exceeds some length?

Comment: check out this http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf You could create a function to cut down variable length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that wraps long split labels over multiple
lines.  The maximum length of each line is 25 characters. Change the
25 to suit your purposes.  (This example is derived from Section 6.1 in
the [rpart.plot vignette](http://www.milbo.org/doc/prp.pdf).)

```
tree <- rpart(Price/1000 ~ Mileage + Type + Country, cu.summary)

split.fun <- function(x, labs, digits, varlen, faclen)
{
    # replace commas with spaces (needed for strwrap)
    labs <- gsub(",", " ", labs)
    for(i in 1:length(labs)) {
        # split labs[i] into multiple lines
        labs[i] <- paste(strwrap(labs[i], width=25), collapse="\n")
    }
    labs
}

prp(tree, split.fun=split.fun)
```